# VS2010 Project Configuration - Anti Reverse Engineering Friendly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reverse-engineering

I am searching for some good tricks of project settings in Visual Studio 2010 to get binary harder to reverse engineering.

Comment: I think .NET and C++ solutions will be welcome, i searching for .NET and C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one: run a protector in post-build event.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on as much optimization as you can without making your program crash, this will make the resultant binaries MUCH harder to reverse engineer.  You can get address-space layout randomization through the linker option.  Otherwise, there are obvious things like building a release version instead of a Debug version, Since 2003 Visual Studio comes with Dotfuscator, which does a good job of protecting .NET programs. To add to Abyx's comment, some protectors, like Software Passport and Oreans products allow you to insert anti-tampering things during the compilation process, which is much more effective than just applying the packer to the compiled binary.

Answer (score 0):

Use Obfuscator (standard in visual studio 2010). It scrambles your code when compiled so when it is decompiled it will not be readable.